# Providing for each year / month the number of new vs repeat clients

Tags: mysql, sql, date

Hi: from a source table named `orders`, which looks like this below, I'd like to get the number of new clients for each month. My source table looks like this:

```
  client|order_id|date_order    
    111|50|2019-01-03
    122|51|2019-02-05
    111|52|2019-02-03
    133|53|2019-03-13
    144|54|2019-04-23    
    122|55|2019-05-15
    133|56|2019-05-17
    161|62|2019-06-07
    163|65|2019-07-22
    172|66|2019-08-10
    111|84|2019-08-18     
    ...|...|...
```

I'd like to get per year, month the number of new vs repeat customer. This is was the output should look like:

```
    year|month|new|repeat_cust|total
    2019|01|1|0|1
    2019|02|1|1|2
    2019|03|1|0|1
    2019|04|1|0|1
    2019|05|0|2|2
    2019|06|1|0|1
    2019|07|1|0|1
    2019|08|1|1|2

Thank you for your help.
```

Comment: Please add column headers to your original table.

Comment: Note that `order` is a reserved word in sql, making it an irritating choice as a table/column identifier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the first time someone ordered using a window function (available in MySQL 8+) and then use that information for aggregation:

```
select year(date), month(date),
       count(distinct case when first_date = date then client end) as new,
       count(distinct case when first_date < date then client end) as repeat,
       count(distinct client) as total 
from (select t.*, min(date) over (partition by client) as first_date
      from t
      group by client
     ) t
group by year(date), month(date);
```

Note:  Based on your definitions, this can count a client twice if they have two orders in the first month they purchase.  You might actually want:

```
select year(date), month(date),
       count(distinct case when first_date = date then client end) as new,
       (count(distinct client) -
        count(distinct case when first_date = date then client end) 
       ) as repeat,
       count(distinct client) as total 
from (select t.*, min(date) over (partition by client) as first_date
      from t
     ) t
group by year(date), month(date);
```

EDIT:

In earlier versions, you can use a `group by` and `join` for the same effect:

```
select year(date), month(date),
       count(distinct case when first_date = date then client end) as new,
       (count(distinct client) -
        count(distinct case when first_date = date then client end) 
       ) as repeat,
       count(distinct client) as total 
from t join
     (select t.client, min(date) as first_date
      from t
     ) c
     using (client)
group by year(date), month(date);
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon: I get an error _"check the manual [...] for the right syntax to use near '(partition by client) as first_date FROM `orders`) t_  PS: I've added the table's name and updated a column's name. Perhaps you could update accordingly.

Comment: @SamanthaAlexandria . . . I've clarified that this approach works in MySQL 8+.  I've edited the answer for earlier versions.

Comment: Thank you for the update. I use earlier <8 version. Your code executes but renders only 1 line.  _ps: I have changed 'repeat' into 'repeat_cust'_

Comment: I have added a `GROUP BY client` after `from t` and it works! Thank you!